# Is there a way to launch any browser in elevated/admin mode from selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to launch Edge Canary , chrome browsers in elevated mode through selenium code on both windows and Mac platforms

Comment: Have you tried to run your code in elevated privilege? On windows right click and run as admin. On macOS using sudo.

Comment: Yes manually I am able to do it, but want to implement through Selenium code.
For e.g. in the below piece of code ,want to know how to implement to launch the browser as "Run as administrator" 

System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","C:\\msedgedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\Users\\xyz\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge SxS\\Application\\msedge.exe");
EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions().merge(chromeOptions);
driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");

Please guide me here.